# Cómo ajustar márgenes y resolver estos problemas en el encabezado?

Tags: html, css, background, margin

tengo una duda que he intentado resolver y buscar información sobre ello, pero no e encontrado nada al respecto.

Vereís, mi pregunta es, al escribir un código html y querer poner un encabezado, quiero poner que se vea de forma completa, ya que, tanto por los lados como por arriba, se queda un espacio de otra clase css, que tiene otro color, adjunto unas fotos y el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

```css
#comida {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>USB 3.0 64GB</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="comida.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="comida">USBDECONFIANZA</h2>
    <h2>Lo mejor para los Mejores</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Ahora adjunto algunas imágenes de que pasa al ejecutar el HTML, lo estoy haciendo a través de VS Code.

[image]

Como ven, quedan como una especie de márgenes, alguien sabe algo? Gracias por todo.

Comment: Por cierto, el h1 no lo cierras bien, lo estas cerrando con H2 (no tiene que ver con tu problema, pero ponlo bien)

Answer (score 0):

Quizás lo hace el navegador por defecto, aún así puedes forzarlo con `margin:0px` y `padding: 0px` en el **body** y en el **h1**:

```css
#comida {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>USB 3.0 64GB</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="comida.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="comida">USBDECONFIANZA</h1>
  <h2>Lo mejor para los Mejores</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Recomendación que puede ayudar también... Agrega a tu css este selector para que aplique al documento en general antes de aplicarlo a cada atributo`* { padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}`

Comment: @GabrielYturrino puede.. o puede que no... yo lo veo **muy** peligroso, la verdad, prefiero hacerlo concretamente en los elementos afectados que generalizarlo pues entonces las listas podrian salir desmadradas por ejemplo sin indentación

Comment: Es valido... todo depende creo de lo que vas a implementar y de la experiencia de la persona que lo hará!

Comment: No digo que no sea válido, solo que si no te acuerdas que lo tienes puesto y creas listas o anidas varias listas entonces no se verán como esperas, y digo eso pero podrian ser otros elementos que tambien tengan margenes o paddings preestablecidos... Míralo tu mismo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/8cLmfn1a/